# "Site May be Hacked" google message

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, google-search

How can i know where new posts comes from in `wp_post` wordpress table? google shown me that `Site May be Hacked` message in google search and I get 100 of posts in Wp_post every day. I am tired write delete SQL code everyday. How can Permanently delete them and how can i find what file creates these files

Comment: it might not be code injection, check the post author, change your current admin users to subscriber (create at least one new admin user) disable all unnecessary plugins, and probably the ones that havent been updated lately, look up useful security plugins and also update wp if one is showing. If more action is required, you need to check the filesystems files there is quite a bit of work in this.Also any plugins allow front end posting of posts?

Comment: Install this plugin immediately and run scans: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordfence/ simply removing the posts from your DB does not solve your problem, only hides the symptoms. You still have a gaping security hole somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have adapted following methods when my site was too hacked. And believe me its functioning properly since when I adapted following methods.

- Change the default username "admin"
- Update your wordpress and all relative plugins to the latest version
- Scan your sites and remove any suspicious files and codes
- If there are other users then limit them to "Subscribers"
- Add a secure plugin for such attacks
- Use captcha code (also in wp-admin's login) whenever there is form submission and always use validations for form.
- Use plugin "[Wordfence plugin](https://www.wordfence.com/)" for security. I have found it very helpful.

Hope these helps.

Comment: I found this link useful to solve my issue `https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/190597?hl=en`

Answer (score 1):

If you're getting hundreds of posts each day and you didn't put them there, your site has *definitely* been pwned (hacked) by a cybercriminal. This site is no longer yours. It now belongs to the criminal.

This is not good. You need to shut down the site immediately: the criminal who took it from you may also be using it for attacks on other computers or sites. Your hosting service or internet service provider will probably blame you for this problem if the criminal starts using a lot of bandwidth. You don't want that.

You may want to ask your hosting service for help with this shutdown if you're not sure what to do.

How to shut it down? Delete all the php files (in other words, get rid of your WordPress installation).

You really do need to do this shutdown if your site's security has been compromised.  It takes a great deal of skill to clean up a compromised site and it's still risky. It takes much less skill to wipe it out and then rebuild it.

You'll need to rebuild the valuable parts of your site from scratch, unfortunately.

But before you add any of your precious content to your newly re-installed WordPress site, please do the following:

1. Activate the akismet plugin.
2. Change both the user name and password of the administrative user.
3. install and activate the BruteProtect plugin.
4. Install and active a security plugin. I like Bulletproof Security, but there are several.
5. The Jetpack plugin has some security features too.
6. Backups are always good. If you're pwned again, recovery will be easier next time.

Plan on keeping your core WordPress, your plugins, and your themes up to date.

Good luck. This is a nasty problem.